# How to disable user-defined functions and classes at runtime in PHP?

Tags: php

Is it possible to disable user-defined functions and/or classes at runtime ? I don't want to overload functions, just disable it like the `disable_functions` and `disable_classes` directives do.

Comment: maybe [runkit_method_remove](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-remove.php)?

Comment: runkit_method_remove is still experimental, and i don't want to remove it. Just disable and enable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to wrap the functions you want to disable.

```
$disabled_funcs = [];

// original code
function func ($msg) {
  echo "$msg\n";
}

//The wrapped one:

function _func () {
  global $disabled_funcs;
  $func = substr (__FUNCTION__, 1);
  if (isset($disabled_funcs[$func]))
    throw new Exception ("Function $func is disabled.");
  return call_user_func_array ($func, func_get_args());
}

function disable_func ($name) {
    global $disabled_funcs;
    $disabled_funcs[$name] = 1;
}

function enable_func ($name) {
    global $disabled_funcs;
    if (isset($disabled_funcs[$name]))
        unset ($disabled_funcs[$name]);
}

//Call the function:
_func ("Func not disabled.");
disable_func ("func");
try {
    _func ("Exception will be raised, this will not be displayed");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
enable_func ("func");
_func ("Func enabled");
```

See the fiddle: http://ideone.com/yQaAtq